# Running a specific instrumentation unit test with Gradle

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle

Is there a way to run a specific Android instrumentation unit test using Gradle? I've tried

```
gradle -Dtest.single=UnitTestName connectedInstrumentTest
```

but it seems to run all the tests in the package.

Answer (score 28):

Using `test.single` appears to be deprecated. The new correct way to do this is

```
./gradlew :<module>:test --tests <pattern>
```

where `<pattern>` could be something like:

- `com.example.MyTest` to run all test methods in com.example.MyTest
- `*MyTest` to match every method in every class whose name ends with MyTest
- `*.MyTest.myMethod` to run a specific test method in class MyTest in any package

If you have a multi-project build, make sure to give the module path before the `test` task; otherwise you'll get a misleading error message when it searches for your test pattern in every subproject.

None of this is documented on the Gradle site anywhere I could find it.

Comment: Sure it's a module with the java plugin applied? Sure it's not an ancient version of Gradle?

Comment: Yup, using gradle 2.10 and android gradle plugin 2.0.0-beta2

Comment: Could you complete your answer with some examples?

Comment: My answer already contains examples. Is there something wrong with them?

Comment: I get `Unknown command-line option '--tests'` if I do `./gradlew test --tests *MyTest`, but it works fine if I do `./gradlew testStagingDebug --tests *Mytest`. (My project has flavors, so `testStagingDebug` is the task I normally run to execute tests, although the `test` task exists and works.)

Comment: You seem to get `Unknown command-line option '--tests'` unless you specify either a wildcard in the pattern OR use :<module>:testDebug (or some other flavor)

Comment: Instead of `--tests` I got the following to work `./gradlew :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.locuslabs.android.sdk.TestActivityTest` thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49403467/2848676

Comment: To be clear @ChrisJones' answer is for **local** unit tests. If you want to run **instrumented** (unit) tests you need to use Michael Osofsky answer

Answer (score 28):

This works if you're using an `instrumentationTestRunner`:

```
./gradlew test -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=<pkg>.YourClassName
```

Using gradle 2.10 and android gradle plugin 2.0.0-beta2.

Since you know what test(s) you want to run, you probably know which module / flavor to use too. You can help Gradle out by specifying the exact module and Gradle task. So if your test is in the `app` module and you want to test the `debug` flavor:

```
./gradlew app:connectedDebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=<pkg>.YourClassName
```

You can get even more fancy with the `tests_regex` argument instead:

```
./gradlew app:connectedDebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.tests_regex=PartialClassName*
./gradlew app:connectedDebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.tests_regex=partialMethodName*
```

Comment: This is the only version that actually works for instrumentation tests with the Android Gradle plugin 2.0 and later. The syntax is more then fugly, but yeah...

Comment: This also worked for running a test on connected phone: `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class='<pkg>.YourClassName'`

Comment: For testing a specific package it is `-Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.package=my.package`

Comment: I always forget this and have to keep coming back here to look this up. So I wrote a quick shell script that may be helpful to others: https://gist.github.com/tir38/1266cbf745f0077b0bbb8e54bf255f8f

Comment: To run a specific unit test:
`./gradlew connectedDevAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.StringUtilTest#testSelectLanguageFragment`

To run tests from 2 specific classes (separate with comma):
`./gradlew connectedDevAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.StringUtilTest,com.example.OtherTest`

Answer (score 21):

The pattern is `-D<testTaskName>.single=<TestClass>` so in your example it should be:

```
gradle -DconnectedInstrumentTest.single=UnitTestName connectedInstrumentTest
```

> NOTE: This answer is outdated. You should use the `--tests` switch in the latest versions of Gradle. (see other answers for an explanation)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't help. `gradlew -DconnectedInstrumentTest.single=UnitTestName connectedInstrumentTest` also launches all tests.

Comment: Is `UnitTestName` a class name or a test method name? It has to be a class name.

Comment: It's a class name. I've also tried to add a package name, but it didn't work either.

Comment: I have this situation too. In my case, `./gradlew -Dtest.single=SimpleTest test`. However it runs all test I have. I have about 11 tests and I want to run only 1 test in **SimpleTest** class.

Comment: @IvanGromov I solved this. someone solved this problem and made his own plugin in his github.

Comment: TestClass is a path, not a classname. At least that way I can run the one class I need

Comment: what do u mean? it did not work? no solution was discussed here?

Answer (score 7):

Since Android gradle plugin 1.1.0-rc1, one can run single test class using `--tests` flag by executing:

```
./gradlew app:testDebug --tests=com.example.MyTest
```

See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Running-from-Gradle

Comment: reference link change, this should be correct for time being https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line

Answer (score 1):

You gotta check this out.

https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test

I made an issue in this github repository, and this guy solved my problem and upload to maven, so in my build.gradle file I use this plugin.

Instructions are written in his repository. you can easily follow it.

After using this android-unit-test plugin, I can use like

```
../gradlew -Dtest.single=SomeTest test
```

or

```
../gradlew -Dtest.single=SomeTest clean check
```

Now it's working and I could only run the specific tests I want to

Answer (score 1):

You should not forget to specify a build variant name after `test` property declaration like

`-Dtest<buildVariantName>=<yourTestName>`.

Like if you have a `debug` build type which gives you `debug` variant after compilation, then if you want to run a test only for this build variant you should declare a command like this:

`./gradlew -DtestDebug=UnitTestName testDebug`

Answer (score 0):

Erdi's answer didn't work for me but I have a single parent for all my test classes so I was able to do this:

```
public abstract class BaseEspressoTest<T extends Activity> extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T> {
    //...
    @Override
    protected void runTest() throws Throwable {
        if(getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MyTestClassName")) {
            super.runTest();
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

This executes only `MyTestClassName`. We can extend it further to execute only specific test  method (or methods):

```
public abstract class BaseEspressoTest<T extends Activity> extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T> {
    //...
    @Override
    protected void runTest() throws Throwable {
        if("MyTestClassName".equals(getClass().getSimpleName()) 
           && "testMethodName".equals(getName())) {
            super.runTest();
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the Gradle command does not work for me. 
I used below mentioened adb command.
for this you need to build your apk first.

adb shell am instrument -w -r -e package  -e debug false .debug.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner