# './gradlew -Dtest.single=SimpleTest test' runs all tests I have

Tags: android, testing, gradle, android-studio, robolectric

My project is normal Android project created on **Android Studio**.

[image: project structure]

I googled a lot to run a single test(tests in SimpleTest, 1 test in this case), everyone say that I should do like

```
./gradlew -Dtest.single=SimpleTest test
```

in my root folder.

or I did in my inner project folder

```
../gradlew -Dtest.single=SimpleTest test
```

I tried so many ways like this but it always run all tests I have.(11 tests in all Classes)

Is there a problem on my build.gradle or is there a something I missing?

Here is my **build.gradle** file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'

        classpath 'com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test:1.0.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 18
        // I changed this for this question
        packageName "com.XXX.XXXX"
    }

    sourceSets {
        instrumentTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-unit-test'

dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile group:'com.squareup.picasso', name:'picasso', version:'2.1.1'
    compile group:'com.squareup.okhttp', name:'okhttp', version:'1.2.1'
    compile group:'com.squareup', name:'otto', version:'1.3.4'

    compile group:'com.jakewharton', name:'butterknife', version:'3.0.0'

    compile group:'com.github.kevinsawicki', name:'http-request', version:'5.4.1'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.2'
    testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'

    instrumentTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    instrumentTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.2'
    instrumentTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
}

tasks.withType(Compile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
        events 'started', 'passed'
    }
}
```

Comment: `-Dtest.single` is the right way to run a single test class or method when using the `java` plugin. Things might be different for the `android-unit-test` plugin.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Thank you for comment. Does it mean that I should find a specific solution for android-unit-test?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser you gave me a clue :) I figured out `android-unit-test` plugin still doesn't support `-Dtest.single` option by asking this to developer of this plugin at `Github`. He made a new patch for this and uploaded new version to Maven, So finally now I can run a single test class :) If you answer my question about this, I'll take that :)

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565857/running-a-specific-unit-test-with-gradle/35585778#35585778

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@PeterNiederwieser` gave me a clue. I got a new Android Studio plugin for `Robolectric` from https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test

Anyone who want the same solution like me can solve the problem using this project.

Also you can use it in `build.gradle` like

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()

}

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
        classpath 'com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test:1.0.1'
    }
}
```

and now `../gradlew clean check -Dtest.single=SomeTest` works well.

Answer (score 9):

The notation

```
-Dtest.single=SimpleTest
```

means that in the task named 'test' run only SimpleTest. If your test task name differs you have to change the system property. E.g. your test task is named 'instrumentationTest' the property must be

```
-DinstrumentationTest.single=SimpleTest
```

cheers,
René

Comment: Thank you for comment :) I'm a newbie on gradle or Android Studio, so I just use the default test. instrumentTest isn't my custom task. Actually, If I run like `./gradlew instrumentTest`, It says **there is no task like this**. That's why I just run **test** for SimpleTest.

Comment: And I tested running `../gradlew -DinstrumentTest.single=SimpleTest test`, it runs all tests I have.

Comment: so your test task is simply named "test"? Can you check if putting the `-Dtest.single=...` part **after** the task makes a difference: `../gradlew test -Dtest.single=SimpleTest` ? It shouldn't, but you'll never know

Comment: Yeah, I tried `../gradlew test -Dtest.single=SimpleTest` and `../gradlew test -DinstrumentTest=SimpleTest` but still runs all tests.

Answer (score 4):

this is what worked for me:

`./gradlew testDebug --tests *TaskCommandSpec`

Use `testDebug` or `testRelease` instead of just `test`.
If you have build variants then use e.g `testProRelease`

docs: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html

Answer (score 0):

Run every classes in the `admob` package:

```
./gradlew clean test --tests "admob.*"
```

Run single test class:

```
./gradlew clean test --tests SimpleTest
```

Run single test method in `SimpleTest` class:

```
./gradlew clean test --tests SimpleTest.simpleMethod
```