# How can I run a single instrumentation test with Gradle Android

Tags: android, testing, robotium, android-testing

I'm trying to run the tests with this line... but this launches all tests:

```
./gradlew -DconnectedAndroidTest.single=LandingActivityTests connectedAndroidTest
```

How can I launch a single test?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a specific instrumentation unit test with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565857/running-a-specific-instrumentation-unit-test-with-gradle)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can run the single android test in two steps:

1. `./gradlew installDebugAndroidTest`
2. `adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.example.MyInstrumentationTest#testFoo  com.example.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`

   https://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html

Comment: For my instrumentation test I had to replace 'runner_class' parameter with com.example.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

Answer (score 52):

Since Android Gradle plugin version 1.3.0 you can use

```
./gradlew -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=your.package.LandingActivityTests connectedAndroidTest
```

Comment: Gradle has -D option to specify system properties, which are passed to JVM, and that makes me think JVM-based tests can be accomplished using only gradlew shell command.
Somebody happens to know where to dig information for properties of instrumentation or unit-testing tests?

Comment: The OP is asking about `connectedAndroidTest`, i.e. tests than run on the device / emulator. Unit tests running in the JVM are a different topic. That said, you may want to have a look at the "Running from Gradle" section at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support.

Comment: This is the best answer, considering the **current** circumstances

Comment: I wish this were the accepted answer. I come to this page all the time to copy-paste this line. It'd be easier if it were at the top of the page.

Comment: Does this still work in recent Android Gradle plugin versions? I cannot get it to work in AGP 8.0.2:

Task '.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.company.app.SourceTest' not found in root project 'Root' and its subprojects.

Answer (score 13):

if you want to run just one test inside the class do something like

```
./gradlew -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=my.app.package.register.RegisterEmailTest#can_register connectedAndroidTest
```

`can_register` is a method in a class `RegisterEmailTest`

NOTE: the package needs to reference where the class is otherwise it will not work.

Comment: It was not working for me because of `modules` but for others if you want to run a particular TestClass in a particular `module` then you can use:

`$ ./gradlew -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.blah.blah.MyActivityTest <modulename>:connectedAndroidTest`

Comment: Definitely simpler than accepted answer! See https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor:testInstrumentationRunnerArguments for more info.

Comment: It will run all the test methods in the class. the part #methodName is ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Visit [Testing](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html)
Sadly, `gradle connectedAndroidTest` task is not supporting all the arguments.
There is [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68029) for gradle team.
If you are using Android Studio, you can create Run Configuration that launches specific test via `adb shell am instrument`

Comment: What about for jvm-based tests?