# How to run unit test on a android module?

Tags: android, gradle, junit, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I have a android project that has multiple library modules and I am trying to test a specific package that contains all modules.

I tried this command:

```sh
./gradlew -Dtest.single=com.moduleone* testProductionDebug
```

And it does not work: it doesn't execute the tests inside this module, but instead executes all the unit tests in the main project package class.

How do I test just the one module?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951421/how-can-i-run-a-single-test-with-gradle-android

Answer (score 1):

You can use test suits: https://developer.android.com/reference/junit/framework/TestSuite.html . Definition of a suit contains classes of tests you need

Comment: Compatible with robolectric?

Comment: But TestSuites should be in the same module it is testing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to execute a gradle task against a single module rather than the entire project, you can supply the name of the module in front of the task separated by a colon (`module_name:task`)

Per your question, this would look something like
`./gradlew -Dtest.single=com.moduleone* your_library_module:testProductionDebug`

This is a simple example, assuming you have a simple project setup. You can also find further reading on this in the gradle docs for [executing a multi-project build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html#sec:executing_a_multiproject_build)