# Running instrumented Android test produces "Unknown command-line option '--tests' "

Tags: android, testing, gradle, fastlane

I need to run tests with Gradle in a specific package of my app with a command line, in a fastfile.
I'm using this command

```
sh './gradlew test --tests "com.package.exemple.*"'
```

but it give me this error

> Problem configuring task :app:test from command line.
>
> >Unknown command-line option '--tests'.

I tried a lot of variants but no one worked.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 5):

There is an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230472) related to this problem. Please star it and use a specific variant name.

> Currently the top-level "test" task doesn't accept the "--tests"
>   argument. Instead, you must run the explicit "test" task for a specific
>   variant (e.g. "testDebugUnitTest").

The syntax you are using is correct as documented  [in the Gradle User Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#test_filtering).

But it seems the `VariantName` can be mandatory as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31410730/1009132).

You can find an example [in the Android Developers Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line.html).

> Gradle also allows you to target specific tests using the --tests
>   flag. For example, the following command runs only the
>   sampleTestMethod tests for the specified build variant...
>
> `./gradlew testVariantName --tests *.sampleTestMethod`

Comment: It clearly will not get ever fixed, is there some workaround for that?