# Gradle Android test does not support filter (--tests)

Tags: android, gradle, filter, android-testing

Gradle Android test does not support filter (--tests).

```
 gradlew test --tests com.example.test.*
```

works.

```
 gradlew connectedAndroidTest --tests com.example.test.*
```

Error: Unknown command-line option '--tests'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running instrumented Android test produces "Unknown command-line option '--tests' "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42209348/running-instrumented-android-test-produces-unknown-command-line-option-tests)

Answer (score 14):

To run specific AndroidJUnit4 tests providing instrumentation runner is necessary to gradle.

try this format:

```
./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.android.testing.blueprint.ui.espresso.EspressoTest
```

Here is the list of all useful gradle commands [{LINK}](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/blob/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint/README.md#custom-gradle-command-line-arguments)

Comment: This worked for Android using Gradle 4.1 except in my case I ran it like `./gradlew :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.locuslabs.android.sdk.TestActivityTest`

Answer (score 0):

For all the tests in a package you can use

```
./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.package=com.mypackage.tests
```