# How to run single test class in Android using Gradle command?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, android-instrumentation, android-junit

In my Android application I have several test classes. If I run following command `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` it runs all the test cases inside the android test folder and generate test report for all test classes but I need to test a specific test class and generate report for the test class I tried with the following command:

```
./gradlew test --tests com.login.user.UserLoginTest
```

The above command throws following exception

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Problem configuring task :app:test from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '--tests'.

* Try:
Run gradlew help --task :app:test to get task usage details. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


My app gradle version is 3.3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a specific instrumentation unit test with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565857/running-a-specific-instrumentation-unit-test-with-gradle)

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/49403467/1172181

Answer (score 25):

It's possible that you are getting this error if you have multiple flavours in your project.
Instead of using just `test`, try a specific test task:

```
./gradlew testDebugUnitTest --tests com.login.user.UserLoginTest
```

Comment: Generally you will also need to specify the module the test is in, e.g., `./gradlew :app:testDebugUnitTest --tests com.login.user.UserLoginTest` for the `app` module.

Comment: tried version 3.6.0, not working. option --tests is not recognized.

Comment: The command in this answer works for me, using Gradle 6.5 and AGP 4.1.2. Also see https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line#RunTestsGradle. It's possible to omit the package name and just use the class name.

Comment: This does not seem to work for instrumented tests.