# How to run one test from a subproject with gradlew?

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I have a multi-project build in gradle. It is an android project and the test in question does run when I execute it manually in android studio.
The structure of the project is as follows:

```
.../my-app$ ./gradlew -q projects
[...]
Root project 'my-app'
+--- Project ':myapp'
\--- Project ':mymodel'
[...]
```

I want to execute a single test (class) in `:myapp`.
Due to version constraints I have to use `gradlew` from the project root directory.

The right command to execute a single test seems to be
`./gradlew test --tests my.project.MyTest` but I don't know how to do it with subprojects.

If I run `./gradlew test --tests my.project.MyTest` I get

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Problem configuring task :myapp:test from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '--tests'.
```

with the suggestion to  run `gradle help --task :myapp:test`
That yields

```
> Task :help
Detailed task information for :myapp:test

Path
     :myapp:test

Type
     Task (org.gradle.api.Task)

Description
     Run unit tests for all variants.

Group
     verification
```

and no command line options at all, so I assume I can just leave it out.

`./gradlew test my.project.MyTest` gives
`Task 'my.project.MyTest' not found in root project 'my-app'.`
same for `./gradlew :myapp:test my.project.MyTest`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42262678) to an older question suggests spelling out the variant name which is `./gradlew :myapp:testReleaseUnitTest --tests my.project.MyTest` for me and that yields

```
> Task :myapp:testReleaseUnitTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':myapp:testReleaseUnitTest'.
> No tests found for given includes: [my.project.MyTest](--tests filter)
```

`./gradlew --version` is `7.1`, I've just upgraded to it with `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 7.1` and `gradle wrapper`.
I'm out of ideas at this point. What am I doing wrong? How can I run a single test in the command line?

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for similar issue and came across your question which provided me with some hints.
After some trials, I found out that the syntax to run a specific task of a subproject from root seems to be:

```
./gradlew sub_project:task_name
```

So, for a project structure similar to this:

> Root project: `app`
> +--- subProject `:subapp1`
> +--- subProject `:subapp2`

The command to run `MyTest` test in `subapp1` sub-project from root is:

```
./gradlew subapp1:test --tests MyTest
```

Edit: The source of confusion is:
When running `./gradlew -q projects`, gradle reports sub-projects with a leading `:` character. Don't use it in your commands.